# Simple circuit with resistors

Tags: resistors, resistance

[image: circuit]

> Knowing that I<sub>1</sub> = 100mA, I<sub>3</sub> = 300mA,
>   U<sub>R<sub>2</sub></sub> = 10V, determine R<sub>2</sub>.

So I tried it like this: we know that in parallel connection, the voltage stays the same so U<sub>R<sub>2</sub></sub> = U<sub>R<sub>1</sub></sub> = 10V. Then, R<sub>1</sub> = U<sub>1</sub> / I<sub>1</sub> = 100 Ohm. Also, I<sub>3</sub> = I<sub>2</sub> + I<sub>1</sub> so I<sub>2</sub> = 0.3A - 0.1A = 0.2A and so R<sub>2</sub> = 10 / 0.2 = 50 Ohm.

Is this correct? I'm trying to learn for the exam but something doesn't seem right to me here.

Comment: What is "U" in this context?

Comment: @JYelton In Europe `U` is commonly used for voltage, to prevent confusion between the variable and the unit.

Comment: Edited, per http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/1453/2028

Comment: seems to be star network

Comment: No, R1 and R2 are not in parallel. Their left ends are not connected together so you cannot say that the voltage across them must be the same. Their voltages may turn out to be the same but it's not because they are in parallel.

Comment: @JoeHass - so how do I calculate this if I can't determine the voltage by noting that they're the same in R1 and R2? Performing Y→Δ seems to only complicate things further here. Or is it just that I shouldn't bother about voltages and use Kirchoff's law straight ahead so that I get I2= 300-100= 200mA?

Comment: Yes, use Kirchoff's current law and see immediately that I2 is 200mA. Since the voltage across R2 is given, Ohm's law tells you its resistance. Jippie gave you the right answer. Don't assume that it's a proper Y or that resistors are in parallel just because of the shape of the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct but your method too complicated. If you know I1 and I3, then the resistors R1 and R3 really don't matter. Apply Kirchoff's current law for I1, I2 and I3.

Comment: I see. So by the Kirchoff's law, I can just skip the U_R2 and R_1 part and just calculate I2=I3-I1 which leads straight to the answer, right? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I2= 300-100= 200mA and V2=10V then R2= 10/.2= 50.